# My GPIOs in the overlay file are not defined in devicetree_generated.h, zephyr fails

Tags: nrf52, zephyr-rtos

I am trying to use Zephyr (v.3.2.99) for a small application on the nRF52840 Dev Kit.  I set up an overlay file nrf52840dk_nrf52840.overlay that is being read and processed by cmake. I get the devicetree_generated.h but it lacks the definition of the nodes.

Here is my overlay:

```
/ {
    aliases {
        pwr0 = &pinpwr0;
        eu0  = &pineu0;
        psw0 = &pinsw0;
     };
    pinpwr0: pin_pwr_0 {
        gpios = <&gpio1 10 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        label = "power";
    };

    pineu0: pin_eu_0 {
        gpios = <&gpio1 11 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        label = "eu";
    };

    pinsw0: pin_sw_0 {
        gpios = <&gpio1 12 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        label = "switch";
    };

    chosen {
            nordic,nus-uart = &uart0;
    };

};
```

My c file:

...

```
#define PWR_IO DT_ALIAS(pwr0)
#if DT_NODE_HAS_STATUS(PWR_IO, okay)
#define PWR_IO_PIN DT_GPIO_PIN(PWR_IO, gpios)
#else
#error "Cannot find the board"
#define PWR_IO_PIN 0
#endif

static const struct gpio_dt_spec pwr = GPIO_DT_SPEC_GET(PWR_IO, gpios);
```

...

The error:

> zephyr/include/generated/devicetree_generated.h:701:32: error:
> 'DT_N_S_pin_pwr_0_P_gpios_IDX_0_VAL_pin' undeclared here (not in a
> function); did you mean 'DT_N_S_leds_S_led_0_P_gpios_IDX_0_VAL_pin'?
> 701 | #define DT_N_ALIAS_pwr0        DT_N_S_pin_pwr_0
> |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ F:/ncs/v2.2.0/zephyr/include/zephyr/devicetree.h:3901:9: note: in
> definition of macro 'DT_CAT7'  3901 |         a1 ## a2 ## a3 ## a4 ##
> a5 ## a6 ## a7
> |         ^~ F:/ncs/v2.2.0/zephyr/include/zephyr/devicetree/gpio.h:164:9: note: in
> expansion of macro 'DT_PHA_BY_IDX'   164 |
> DT_PHA_BY_IDX(node_id, gpio_pha, idx, pin)
> |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ F:/ncs/v2.2.0/zephyr/include/zephyr/drivers/gpio.h:341:24: note: in
> expansion of macro 'DT_GPIO_PIN_BY_IDX'   341 |                 .pin =
> DT_GPIO_PIN_BY_IDX(node_id, prop, idx),                 
> |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ F:/ncs/v2.2.0/zephyr/include/zephyr/drivers/gpio.h:376:9: note: in
> expansion of macro 'GPIO_DT_SPEC_GET_BY_IDX'   376 |
> GPIO_DT_SPEC_GET_BY_IDX(node_id, prop, 0)
> |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ../src/tvunit.c:25:40: note: in expansion of macro 'GPIO_DT_SPEC_GET'    25 | static const struct
> gpio_dt_spec pwr = GPIO_DT_SPEC_GET(PWR_IO, gpios);

If I look into the file devicetree_generated.h, the token DT_N_S_pin_pwr_0 is never defined (only referred to in the comments).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While I haven't tried it out, it's possible it's not properly processing the `pin_pwr_0` and like nodes as they don't have bindings. Generally, nodes in the devicetree also need bindings to be processed correctly. Since the nodes you are using are just pins/buttons; you should be able to use the generic `gpio-keys` compatible by adding this to each node: `compatible = "gpio-keys";`

Comment: Great, I'll make it a formal answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

Zephyr's build system is not properly processing the `pin_pwr_0` and like nodes as they don't have bindings. Generally, nodes in the devicetree also need bindings to be processed correctly. Since the nodes you are using are just pins/buttons; you should be able to use the generic `gpio-keys` compatible by adding this to each node: `compatible = "gpio-keys";` More on Zephyr's devicetree binding rules can be found here: https://docs.zephyrproject.org/3.2.0/build/dts/bindings.html